# Check if dataframe in text file empty before importation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, is-empty

I am new user of pandas and I need some help. 
I have in one folder 10 txt files:

```
file_date1_1.txt
...
file_date1_5.txt
file_date2_1.txt
...
file_date2_5.txt
```

Each file has the same design:

```
- text to explain the file
- datas.
```

To export one file, I do the following code:

```
Data_Frame = pd.read_csv(Location,  delimiter=r'\s+', index_col=False, header = None, skiprows=11)
```

What I want to do is to do a loop to make a list of dataframes. 
So I did that:

```
for i in range(0,len(files_SE)):
    date.append(files_SE[i][0:7])
    hour.append(files_SE[i][8:13])
    Location.append('\\'.join([adress,files_SE[i]]))
    SE_df.append(pd.read_csv(Location[i],  delimiter=r'\s+', index_col=False, header = None, skiprows=11))
```

(skiprows is to avoid the text before the datas and files_SE is a list with all names files).

But my problem is that the loop stops at f`ile_date1_5.txt` because there is no data in (it is empty).
What I would like is to make a condition such as

```
if (pd.read_csv(Location[i],  delimiter=r'\s+', index_col=False, header = None, skiprows=11)).empty:
    *do nothing*
else:
    *do the importation of the dataframe*
```

Does anyone has a solution for me ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: You could surround the `pd.read_csv` with a `try` `except` statement and just ignore the exception in order to skip files that cannot be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the check like this:

```
Current_Data = pd.read_csv(Location[i],  delimiter=r'\s+', index_col=False, header = None, skiprows=11)
if not Current_Data.empty:
    SE_df.append(Current_Data)
```